# bootstrap website wont scoll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a portfolio webpage on bootstrap. Everything was going fine until I uploaded my code onto bootstrap and my page has simply stopped scrolling and I can't find a solution/identity the piece of code that caused the page to stop scrolling. HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About Me</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zulimarAbout.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arapey" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Nav -->
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav_container" style="overflow: visible; height: 328px; margin-top: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <div class="nav_container_top">
                    <div id="logo"> 
                        <h1 class="name">Zulimar Toro Seda</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_wrap collapsable">
                        <!-- Menu Start -->
                        <ul class="main_nav">
                            <li class="item"><a href="zulimarHomePage.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="item"><a href="ZulimarServicesAndRates.html">Services & Rates</a></li>
                            <li class="item"><a href="zulimarAbout.html">About</a></li>                   
                        </ul>
                        <div id="overlay">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Nav -->

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="content" class="loaded" style="top:0px; margin-top: 0px;" id="allContent">
            <div class="_4ormat_content_wrapper" id="content_page_wrapper">
                <div class="_4ormat_content_page_container _4ormat_sort">
                    <div class="_4ORMAT_content_page_row _4ormat_sort_item m _4ORMAT_module_image_11" data-content-module-id="599402" data-content-module-template-id="35" data-content-module-unique-id="" data-content-module-removable="true" data-content-module-category="image">
                        <div class="twocol spacer"></div>
                            <div class="eightcol">
                                <div data-croppable="true" data-default-shape="landscape" data-editable-type="image" data-height="506" data-landscape-ratio="760:506" data-linkable="true" data-portrait-ratio="2:3" data-width="760" id="image_1-599402" data-default-img="images/bg.jpg" data-dom-id="image_1" data-link-type="none" data-link-value="" data-id="18643087" data-content-module-unique-id="">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="PaulmitchellZu.jpg" class="img" style="float:;">
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_4ORMAT_content_page_row _4ormat_sort_item _4ORMAT_module_text_01" data-content-module-id="599403" data-content-module-template-id="34" data-content-module-unique-id="" data-content-module-removable="true" data-content-module-category="text">
                <div class="threecol spacer"></div>
                <div class="sixcol">
                    <div data-editable-type="text" id="overflow" class="  " data-force-html-mode="false" data-id="18643088" data-content-module-unique-id="">
                        <p>Born in Puerto Rico, bred in Miami, Florida, and now living 
                        as an expat around the world, I use writing, hospitality and working 
                        with boutique and non-profit projects as a way to explore creativity and 
                        as a means to my lifestyle.</p>
                        <p>With a Bachelor's in Hospitality and Event Management, a 
                        theme of working with alternative brands and years of experience since, 
                        in various areas of the field, I've come to learn and mildly obsess over 
                        one thought;</p>
                        <p><span id="quote">"Engagement is the result of a well-curated 
                        experience."</span></p>
                        <p>My passion lies in collaborating and in turn, creating the 
                        unique experience that suits my clients and readers.</p>
                        <p>Every story can be told in a relatable way that attracts your 
                        individual market. As a writer, I do my research and create content that 
                        connects your business to your readers as a medium that enriches their 
                        lives.</p>
                        <p>With a strong background in luxury hospitality, event 
                        coordinating and business development, I wear many hats while 
                        implementing my skills as a virtual assistant.</p>
                        <p>You know those pestering tasks that take up to much time out 
                        of the day? Replying to emails, travel itineraries, marketing launches, 
                        managing social media, and so forth. That’s what I’m here for.</p>
                        <p>I am a hospitality enthusiast, major foodie, travel 
                        connoisseur, self-proclaimed artist and poet with a flair for style and 
                        a hint of edge.</p>
                        <p><span id="zulifique">ZULIFIQUE</span> is my personal writing 
                        platform for the exotic, alternative, and open-minded twenty-somethings 
                        who 
                        wonder to exercise true freedom.</p>
                        <p class="get">Got a project you need a word nerd for? Email me 
                        for more details at zulimar.toro@gmail.com</p>        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="threecol spacer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 style="display: none;"></h2>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS -->
        <div class="social">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
        </div>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript & Jquery-->
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script 
            src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just edited your question to have indentation for your code and I noticed that right after the line `<h2 style="display: none;"></h2>`, you have two unnecessary `</div>` lines.  These should be removed.  I am not saying it is a solution, just that thay are not required.

Comment: Use F12 and find all elements the gives height to your page. If your page is >= the height of the body, there will no be a scrolling to do.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "uploaded my code onto bootstrap"? I pasted your code into a code pen and it scrolls fine. In order for us to assist you, it would be beneficial if you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you Nic3500 for helping me edit my code. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you jmag I'm not sure what you mean by F12, but I edited both the width and heght of my body and I'm still unable to scroll down when viewing the site. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Ryan Gibbs, what I mean is I created a code for a website and I'm using bootstrap to host it. But when I insert my code into the bootstrap platform and preview it your only able to view half the website. It won't allow me to scroll down. Does this help?